# How to create a Java EE 7 Maven IntelliJ Project

Tags: maven, jpa, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, java-ee-7

I am new to Stack Overflow because of my frustration to build a working `Java EE 7` Project with `Maven` and `IntelliJ ultimate`.

I learned a lot about `JPA` and `JSF` in the last weeks and am thrilled to put my knowledge to use but unfortunately I am not able to create a working project structure as I get all sorts of errors along the way. I haven't found a single up to date tutorial which is working on the entire Internet.

My greatest achievement is creating a `Maven` project, and run the `index page` on a `Jboss Wildfly` (11) server.

I know `Maven` (3) requires a certain structure to work, I read that it is the one in picture 1.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9Ad0.png)

Furthermore I know that I can add framework support by right clicking the project name and that I can add facets or modules by selecting files and project structure.

I would be very thankful if someone could explain the right creation of such a project. I already wasted double digit hours and lost a lot of fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to create a Maven Project with IntelliJ. After that I added JavaEE Application under Framework Support and checked the boxes for JSF and Web Application under Java EE aswell.

Now this doesn't work alone, I had to put this in the right structure Maven requires. I moved the META-INF Folder to main/src/resources. After renaming the web Folder to webapp, I moved it to src/main.

To check, go to Project Structure/ Facets and check if the paths are set correctly.

After adding a local Wildfly 11 Server Artifact (war), IntelliJ starts the default browser and I get to the index page.

[The Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5cY7.png)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take a look at JetBrains page, they have a lot of tutorials on how to use their products. Here how to create new Maven project: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven.html#maven_create_project

Also, here you have information how an example pom.xml file looks like and how to build it: 

 
https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html 

When you develop your project you can add dependencies to the pom.xml file